# How to find all possible splits of a set?

Tags: java

I need to split a set A into two sets B and C, and find all possible splits of A' elements in B and C.

So when first split size is 2 then

> [abcd] ->[ab] [cd], [ac] [bd], [cd] [ab]..

And when first split size is 1 then

> [abcd] -> [b] [acd], [a] [bdc], [d] [abc]..

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: You are trying to create all permutations for a given length. This one is for strings, but the technique is the same: 
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/

Comment: it is not permutation. abcd and bacd are different permutations but if you split in middle. Both splits are same. This is a combination problem.

Comment: hmm ok i understood the question wrong then :)

Comment: Right, it's not about permutations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use apache commons math util for java. If your are using maven add its dependency in pom otherwise manually download and add the jar.

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/Combinations.html

```
//n is no of elements. k is k-combinations
public Combinations(int n, int k)

//you can use this method to get every combination    
public Iterator<int[]> iterator()
```

This will give you all k-combinations and values will be in terms of indexes. you need to convert index to element.

if array arr, you can do arr[i].
if list, list.get(i)

Comment: That worked like a charm! For my example above I set N=4 and k=2, iterate over all k-combinations, use them as indexes for A (so I got the first split) and then remove those from a copy of A (which is the second split).

Comment: cool. instead of creating another copy of A, you can have a set(or list) which contains integers. Initialize with all indexes  and then you can use set.removeAll(Arrays.asList(first split int[])) to get second split indexes. may reduce the no of lines. if you do it this way, you will always have one copy of A and splits are identified by the indexes. If you want it resolved, you can use A[i] anytime. Point is try to avoid duplicating the Original array so your code will be neat and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean an algorithmn like this? I wrote it quickly an hopefully it helps:

```
public void split(int s, String list1, String list2){
    if(s > list1.length()){
        System.err.println("To big s");
        return;
    }
    if(s == 0){
        System.out.println(list2 + " "+ list1);
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < list1.length(); i++){
            String temp = list1.substring(0, i) + list1.substring(i+1, list1.length());
            String temp2 = list2 + list1.charAt(i);
            split(s-1, temp, temp2);
    }       
}
```