# Find All Binary Splits of a Nominal Attribute

Tags: python, split, combinations, permutation, decision-tree

#### Question

I'm trying to build a binary decision tree classifier in Python from scratch based on a data set that has only nominal attributes.

One step I'm stuck on is finding all possible ways to compute a binary split of a nominal attribute.  For example, for an attribute with possible values [a, b, c, d], I am looking for a way to split these in two arrays such that we obtain:

```
  left     right
  ----     -----
  a        bcd
  b        acd
  c        abd
  d        abc
  ab       cd
  ac       bd
  ad       bc
```

without duplicate splits (e.g. we don't need "bc" in `left` and "ad" in `right` since this would yield the same binary split as "ad" in `left` and "bc" in `right`).  Order within each split is also irrelevant (e.g. "ad" is the same as "da" in one side of a split).

#### Current Attempt

The exact terminology is escaping me, but I think this is some form of combination/permutation problem.  I know its not quite a powerset I'm after.  The closest question I could find similar to mine is linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34693950/how-to-find-all-possible-splits-of-a-set).

So far I've started an iterative procedure:

```
for i in range(1, array.length / 2):
  for j in range(1, i):
     # stuck here
```

The reason for looping only through the floor of half the length of the attribute's possible values (`array`) is because if we store up to `array.length / 2` values in `left`, right has `1 - (array.length / 2)` values, covering all possible splits.

Also, I've heard of the `itertools` library .. so perhaps there's a way to achieve what I'm after with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `itertools.product` to write a function that splits a sequence into all possible divisions of two halves. I'd iterate through that and remove duplicates using a set.

```
import itertools

def binary_splits(seq):
    for result_indices in itertools.product((0,1), repeat=len(seq)):
        result = ([], [])
        for seq_index, result_index in enumerate(result_indices):
            result[result_index].append(seq[seq_index])
        #skip results where one of the sides is empty
        if not result[0] or not result[1]: continue
        #convert from list to tuple so we can hash it later
        yield map(tuple, result)

def binary_splits_no_dupes(seq):
    seen = set()
    for item in binary_splits(seq):
        key = tuple(sorted(item))
        if key in seen: continue
        yield key
        seen.add(key)

for left, right in binary_splits_no_dupes("abcd"):
    print left, right
```

Result:

```
('a', 'b', 'c') ('d',)
('a', 'b', 'd') ('c',)
('a', 'b') ('c', 'd')
('a', 'c', 'd') ('b',)
('a', 'c') ('b', 'd')
('a', 'd') ('b', 'c')
('a',) ('b', 'c', 'd')
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what `itertools.product((0,1), repeat=len(seq))` is doing?  Correct me if I'm wrong: by the looks of it, (0,1) is provided because this is a binary split, but I'm not so sure about `repeat=len(seq)`.  The rest of this code is relatively straightforward as long as we understand what the values returned by itertools.product function represent.

Comment: `result_indices` is a tuple of 0s and 1s, and it is the same length as `seq`. Each 0 indicates "the value in `seq` at this position should go in the left column" and each 1 indicates "the value in `seq` at this position should go in the right column". Examples: A `result_indices` of (0,1,0) separates "ABC" into (("A","C"), ("B",)). A `result_indices` of (1,0,0) separates "ABC" into (("B", "C"), ("A")).

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, your binary splits are also known as [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) with exactly 2 parts. Each 2-partition is fully determined by a subset (the other half of the partition is the complement of the subset), hence the relationship to combinations.

In fact, if you [generate the powerset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6579917/6732794) of your string in [shortlex order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order), you can essentially fold the powerset in half to produce the desired partitions.

```
import itertools

def bsplit(chars):
    "Returns a list of all unique 2-partitions."
    assert len(chars) >= 2

    # first, we generate the powerset in shortlex order,
    # minus the empty set and its complement
    subsets = (itertools.combinations(chars, k) for k in range(1, len(chars)))
    subsets = itertools.chain.from_iterable(subsets)
    subsets = [''.join(sub) for sub in subsets]

    # then, we "fold" the set in half--pairing each subset 
    # in the first half with its complement from the second half
    half = len(subsets) // 2
    return list(zip(subsets[:half], reversed(subsets[half:])))

def test(*strings):
    for string in strings:
        for left, right in bsplit(string):
            print(left, right)
        print()

test('ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'abcde')
```

This also shows that there are [`(2^n - 2) / 2) = 2^(n - 1) - 1)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) partitions of size 2 for a set of size `n`.

Obviously, you can't use this for large sequences because it needs to materialize (almost) the whole powerset all at once. Although, it does suggest an efficient solution that avoids generating duplicates: enumerate the first `2^(n - 1) - 1)` non-empty elements of the ordered powerset, and map each subset to its corresponding partition.